# Problem extending native (es6) classes in Safari

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, safari, prototype, es6-class

I'm having trouble extending the native `WebSocket` class using es6 classes.

The following piece of code works on Chrome and Firefox, but not on Safari:

```
class MyWebSocket extends WebSocket {
    doSomething() {
        console.log('hi');
    }
}

let ws = new MyWebSocket('wss://127.0.0.1:4000');
ws.doSomething();
```

> TypeError: ws.doSomething is not a function. (In 'ws.doSomething()', 'ws.doSomething' is undefined)

`console.log('MyWebSocket.prototype')` lets me see that the function was added to the prototype.
This happens with a few other builtin classes, `Animation` being one, but not with others, like `Date` for example.

Has anyone run into this? Is this a bug in Safari? Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, looks like a bug. The `WebSocket` constructor is probably hardcoded to return a `WebSocket` instance. It doesn't respect `Symbol.species` either.

As a workaround you could use something like this:

```
class MyWebSocket extends WebSocket {
    constructor(url) {
        super(url);
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, MyWebSocket.prototype);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that workaround is exactly what I was looking for. I’ll look at submitting a bug report later tonight.

Comment: At least the URL class in Safari seems to have the same problem. This hack worked.

Comment: Same goes for the `Request` and `Response` objects. The fix works for those as well.

Comment: same goes for WritableStream. Reported a bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=226201